# How to internationalize a Thymeleaf nested list?

Tags: spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

Let's say I have a basic static HTML page that contains a nested unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub-item 2.1</li>
            <li>Sub-item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

That's valid XHTML.  Great.

Now, I'm applying Thymeleaf's internationalization via `th:text` (if it matters, and I don't believe it does, this is inside a Spring application).

```
<ul>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item1}">Item 1</li>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item2}">Item 2
        <ul>
            <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.1}">Sub-item 2.1</li>
            <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.2}">Sub-item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item3}">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Assuming that I have my `mypage.properties` set up and working properly, once the above is processed by Thymeleaf, the result will display as:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Where did my sub-items go for Item 2, and how can I get them back while having them i18n'ed separately?  I know about `th:utext`, but I do not want to have `mypage.item2` contain the full HTML for the entire sublist.  Is it possible?

---

**Edit**: It is possible to get what I'm looking for if I change my code to the following, but then it is no longer valid XHTML.  I am looking for a valid XHTML solution.

```
<ul>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item1}">Item 1</li>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item2}">Item 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.1}">Sub-item 2.1</li>
            <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.2}">Sub-item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item3}">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for understanding: `th:text` change everything till the tag is closed, so the behavior is not a surprise.

```
<ul>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item1}">Item 1</li>
    <li><span th:text="#{mypage.item2}" th:remove="tag">Item 2</span>
       <ul>
        <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.1}">Sub-item 2.1</li>
        <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.2}">Sub-item 2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item3}">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

should work or with newer version you could use [`th:block`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#bloc)

```
<ul>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item1}">Item 1</li>
    <li><th:block th:text="#{mypage.item2}">Item 2</th:block>
       <ul>
        <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.1}">Sub-item 2.1</li>
        <li th:text="#{mypage.item2.2}">Sub-item 2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li th:text="#{mypage.item3}">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

With [`th:inline`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) it should be possible to avoid the extra node `th:block`.

Comment: Gah.  I never even considered creating a child `<span>` just for the i18n aspect.  Thanks.

Comment: Well the extra block <th:block> or <span> is the price you must pay for a clean html-template.